# Not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL

Tags: openedx, edx, lms

I have been using open-EDX (LMS) - (Juniper Version) Devstack Installation for Ubuntu 18.04 (which uses Docker Containers). I recently git cloned edx-proctoring into the place where I am using Devstack such that my folder structure would be like:

openEDX/credentials (or) devstack (or) edx-platform (or) edx-proctoring ....etc......

Now, I need to Install the cloned folder into my pre-existing devstack development. I am using these instructions:
***https://github.com/edx/edx-proctoring/blob/master/docs/developing.rst***

I am stuck in the Sub-section: ***Install the proctoring package into edx-platform in the container, for both LMS and Studio***
Under Section:
***How do I develop on edx-proctoring?***
I provided the correct path for the git-cloned folder inside private.txt file.
Now, after entering into make lms-shell, when I am trying to call ***paver install_prereqs***
it is giving me this error:
***ERROR: /folder-path/ is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+).***

No matter what path I give (like via root folder, via absolute path) the same error is repeating.
I am out of solutions. I would really appreciate suggestions and help.

Thank You.